# Using exponential decay function to predict outcome

Tags: statistics, exponential-function

Let's say I have a graph that follows the function $y= ae^{-bx}$ , and I'm trying to predict the chlorine residue left in a pool after a certain amount of time.

So for $2$ hours, the chlorine residue is at $1.6$ ppm (parts per million) and 
for $4$ hours, $1.5$ ppm. Tabulating the data gives:

- $6$ hours, $1.45$ ppm
- $8$ hours, $1.42$ ppm
- $10$ hours, $1.38$ ppm
- $12$ hours, $1.36$ ppm

Now I'm trying to predict what the concentration would be at $15$ hours using the decaying curve above.

I've tried to figure it out so far and I don't really know where to start. I've tried plugging in the different values into the function but obviously I'm getting various answers depending on which "hours/ppm" combo I'm using.

Comment: You might want to start by assuming that the base is $e$ (the base of the natural logarithm), and then take the natural logarithm of both sides. This linearizes equation, so that you can use least squares to find the appropriate values of $a$ and $c$.

Comment: @Auslander Could you explain a little bit more in depth on how to do this?

Comment: Take care ! The data do not look to follow an exponential model. Plot $\log(y)$ as a function of $t$. You are very far away from something looking like a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expression $y=ae^{bx}$. There is no need to put a negative in front of the $b$ term. It'll come out as negative anyhow. Then linearize the equation as follows:

\begin{align*}
y&=ae^{bx}\\
\log{y}&=\log(ae^{bx})\\
\log{y}&=\log{a}+\log{e}^{bx}\\
\log{y}&=bx+\log a
\end{align*}
Let $z=\log y$ and $c=\log a$ so that we obtain
$$z=bx+c.$$
Therefore If you want to fit curve $y=ae^{bx}$ to the values $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ we instead fit line $z=bx+c$ to the values 
$$(x_1,z_1),\ldots,(x_n,z_n)=(x_1,\log(y_1)),\ldots,(x_n,\log(y_n))$$
I guess you'll probably want to do this with technology - you're looking to do a linear regression. If you want to understand the underlying theory then perhaps look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html). The value of $b$ will simply be the gradient and $z$ intercept is $c$. To find the value of $a$ note that $a=e^c$.

Note: in all calculations I've use the natural logarithm.

Comment: So where would I plug my 15 value in?

Comment: In one column, you'd put all of time values. In the second column, you'd put all of the logarithms of the concentration values. Then you would do a linear regression.

Comment: This is a preliminary step prior to nonlinear regression since what is measured is $y$ and not $\log(y)$.